# What factor impact network speed between VM significantly?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, network-speed, virtual-network

There is question about network between different server,but i got a different situation.

I have two VM in a server,and I tried to test maximum network speed between two VM.

OS : CentOS

VSwitch speed : 10Gb/s (1.25GB/s)

Virtual network adapter  speed : 10Gb/s

VM used **VSwitch** and **Virtual network adapter** to communicate,and there is no ethernet cable to impact network speed.

```
VM A : nc -l 20000 > /dev/null

VM B : time dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=200 | nc <VM A> 20000

200+0 records in
200+0 records out
20971520000 bytes (21 GB) copied, 122.466 s, 171 MB/s

real    2m2.479s
user    0m2.148s
sys     3m10.841s
```

The above command is used to test **only** network speed(not include disk read and write)

There may some communicate overhead in network.

I thought the network speed should be 1 GB/s,but why the speed is so slow.

What factor impacts the network speed or how can i speedup my network?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you changed the network settings according to your [other question](https://serverfault.com/a/938947/8897) on both machines?

Comment: @Sven yes,I already change to new virtual network adapter,so is now 10 Gb/s speed